# Why does the 'UWSGI listen queue of socket full' error cause a Python application to time out during a third-party API call?

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

According to the logs, before the occurrence of "UWSGI listen queue of socket full", the third-party requests made by the application took only milliseconds.  However, after this occurred, the same requests took more than ten seconds to complete.

"I tried increasing the value of the listen parameter and the number of threads in uwsgi, which resolved the 5xx error in my application.  However, my confusion is that the listen parameter should only affect the efficiency of receiving requests sent by nginx, so why does it affect calling third-party services?"